# jquery multiple jsp tabs

Tags: jsp, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I have researched the net enough, but cant seem to find a solution to this problem.
I have two tabs and each loads from a different JSP. The main JSP( default one) has all the script files included. But when I call the jQuery functions from JSP2,they are not triggered.My understanding is, JSP2 does not have visibility of those functions.
When I copy paste the required jQuery function onto jsp2, everything works as expected. But I dont see why I need to have the script files in 2 places.
Each JSP works as expected when it is run independently.

Here are some snippets from code, Main JSP:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab one</a></li>
<li><a href="config.jsp" title="test">Tab two</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
blah blah </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tabs').tabs();
}

function updateGrid(){
url = "www.google.com";
jQuery("#logGrid").clearGridData();
cache : false,
$.post(url,
function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
         var mygrid = jQuery("#logGrid")[0];
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             jQuery("#logGrid").addRowData(i, data[i]);
         }
  }
});
  }

  jQuery("#logGrid").jqGrid(
       {
          url : '',
          mtype : 'POST',
          datatype : "json",
          rownumbers : true,
          colNames: ["Logger Name","Logger Parent ", "Current Log Level", "Update Log Level To"],
          colModel: [
                       { name: 'loggerName', index: "loggerName", width: 215, editable: true},
                       { name: "loggerParent", index: "loggerParent", width: 100, editable: true },
                       { name: "loggerEffectiveLevel", index: "loggerEffectiveLevel", width: 100, editable: true},
                       { name: "changedLogLevel", index: "changedLogLevel", width: 35, editable: true, edittype:"select", editoptions:{value:"DEBUG:DEBUG;INFO:INFO;WARN:WARN;ERROR:ERROR;FATAL:FATAL"} }
                       ],
          autowidth: true,
          rownumWidth: 40,
          height : $(window).innerHeight(),
          viewrecords: true,
          caption:"Log4j Configuration Log Level",
          cellEdit: true,
          cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
          afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value) {

                    var targetLogLevel = jQuery('#logGrid').getCell(rowid, "changedLogLevel");
                    var targetLogger = jQuery('#logGrid').getCell(rowid, "loggerName");
                    updateLog(targetLogger, targetLogLevel);

  }
```

});

And JSP2 is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  updateGrid();
</script>
<div id="test">
<form id="logGridForm">
    <table id="logGrid"></table>
</form>
 </div>
```

I dont want to copy the script functions into each jsp.. it makes it redundant and looks messy. is there a way around it. Am I doing something wrong here?

I have edited my question to include the jqGrid which is used to populate the data. This where it fails with this exception: Message: 'this.p.rownumbers' is null or not an object URI: localhost:7001/imgRepository/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js

All works fine when I copy the method locally into JSP2.

Comment: What happens when you click on the second tab? Do you load the second tab content using AJAX? Do you refresh the whole page?

Comment: The second tab content is loaded via ajax.. The server shows that the call is a made and data is fetched.. however the page is blank and I see this error on firefox console : uncaught Exception:jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  updateGrid();
</script>

in your first jsp, as jsp compiles at runtime. your second jsp can call that script from first page also.
```

Comment: It does not help. The updateGrid is being called from eitherr of the jsps.. it makes the Ajax call and gets the json data.. but when rendering Im using a jqGrid and I get this exception :
Message: 'this.p.rownumbers' is null or not an object
URI: http://localhost:7001/imgRepository/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js